# Loop not vectorized due to reason '1300'

Tags: c++, vectorization

I am trying to vectorize a loop that does a lot of  iteration (over 300 000 000) to gain some computation time:

```
uint16_t* samples = (uint16_t*)pixmap->samples;

Image image(pixmap->w, pixmap->h);
uint8_t *dest = (uint8_t*)image[0];

for (int x = 0; x < len; x++)
{
    dest[x] = samples[x] & 0xFF;
}
```

But qvec-report say it could not be vectorized due to reason 1300.

According to the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj658585(v=vs.110).aspx), reason 1300 is :

> Loop body contains no—or very little—computation.

Indeed, my loop body does very little computation, but since there is a lot of iteration, it still take some time.

Why does the vectorization is not done in that case ? Is it because it would not be worth it ? If yes, why ?

If no, is there any way or any tricks to "force" it ?

Comment: maybe post the relative assembly to see what is being compiled?

Comment: Since dest is an 8-bit value, the `&` is not needed.  All you are doing is a copy of every other byte of the source, which can be highly optimized by the compiler.

Comment: @stark So you are telling me that vectorization is useless in this case ?

Comment: If there really are 300 million iterations, I can tell you that the loop will be memory bound. So vectorizing it isn't going to help much. Not sure if the compiler is picking up on that.

Comment: @stark: That is probably exactly what's happening: The optimizer first removed the pointless `& 0xFF`, and then the vectorizer found no computation left.

Comment: Indeed, the `& 0xFF` is useless

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically the body of the loop is so simple that it's more efficient to compile it as it is rather than vectorize it as the runtime cost of the vectorization would be greater than executing the code as it is.

There's really no point in trying to force it, as the compiler is telling you that the vectorized version would be less efficient that the non-vectorized version. If you add more computations to the loop the compiler may choose to vectorize it.

Comment: "runtime cost of the vectorization" - huh? like checking the length? With the OP's 300M iterations, that's clearly not the case.

Comment: @Sean I don't want to parallelize my loop since there is already a lot of thread running, I just want to vectorize it. Or maybe I'm missing something

Comment: @Blablablabli - yes, sorry, that was my mistake. I've reverted the answer

Comment: @KarolyHorvath Checking against len is 1 instruction (1 nsec).  The copy in the body of the loop reads and writes to memory (60 nsec each) so checking the length 300M times is entirely hidden by the time spent waiting for cache lines to be read and written.

Comment: @stark: The 60 nsec you quote is latency, but for bulk access like this you need to use the raw memory bandwidth.

Comment: @stark: I would prefer you've addressed that to Sean... (and btw, vectorization.. you clearly won't check 300M times).

Comment: @MSalters  Just an order-of-magnitude estimate.  Obviously bandwidth depends on channels, etc. so could be off by a lot.

Comment: @stark: It's off by about three orders of magnitude. QPI runs at one byte every 0.08 ns, and it's bidirectional so the writing back of `dest[]` doesn't interfere.

Comment: But memory doesn't run as fast as QPI.

Comment: @stark: Still, latency is the wrong metric. Modern CPUs do all they can to predict reading patterns and prefetch the data to be available. Sequential reading and writing is child's play for them.

Answer (score 3):

You're probably confusing the auto-vectorizer (SSE/AVX) and the auto-parallelizer (threads). But that's not the real problem, I suspect: `dest[x] = samples[x] & 0xFF` really means `dest[x] = static_cast<uint8_t>(static_cast<int>(samples[x]) & 0xFF)`. With all those conversions to different widths, it's hard to come up with equivalent SSE code. SSE2 allows you to organize a 128 bit register in 16x8 or 8x16 bits, but here you mix 8 and 16 bits types, and a 32 bit literal.

Comment: In the first place my loop was not mixing type like this, I was just copying one byte every two byte from the source to the dest (using 2 uint8_t *). At that point the loop could not be vectorized since I was not accessing the source pointer memory in a continuous way. Using an uint16_t was my tricks to try to vectorize the loop in the first place